# android view id is not correct

Tags: android, view, listener

I create a whole layout setup in XML then attempt to attach listeners to the buttons using findViewById(). The problem I am having now is that the View parameter I receive in the method does not contain the ID of the view I clicked: 830009633920 vs 2131099657.

```
Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnNext) {
                ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without at least pasting in some code...

Comment: Are you comparing the object id in debug view with the `R` id from the generated resource code?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that is what it was as that is how I grabbed it. I am guessing that is not correct, but why?

Comment: Have you tried logging the following and checking in DDMS? `Log.d("DEBUG", getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()));` That should tell you what you're actually getting there.

Comment: Inside your onClick() if you print out btnNext.getId() is it the same as R.id.btnNext?

Comment: @Tim : btnNext is local.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) 
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnNext:
        ...
        break;

    case R.id.foo:
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would prove complex and slightly annoying as I am doing this for 80+ items (Buttons, EditText, etc), to each its related listener. The onClick method I have will eventually have a switch (or if) statement for about 20 buttons.

Comment: @scott.smart Edited answer. Try that.

Comment: Thats the problem I am having: the `view.getId()` for the button Next isn't R.id.btnNext.

Answer (score 0):

That should be working, so my only guess without seeing the rest of the code or layout is that you have set click handlers on two items that overlap.

If you plan on making an Android Library project switch like this will not work due to a recent change in the tool chain.

http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

In general I find it is much simpler to use an anonymous class the handle clicks rather than a large single handler.

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            ...
        }
    });
```

You might try this approach just to debug that the item you expect to get the click is what you are pressing, to make sure you don't have layout issues.

Comment: Tried, same results. The view passed to onClick is different from the R.id.btnNext.

Comment: I generally take this route too. It makes more sense in my head this way then having one onClick and using a switch to figure out which one was clicked. Also with this way each button has its own listener. So there is no need to check anything against the view that gets passed to you. You know that if onClick() is getting called that it came from the only possible button.

Comment: If the view passed into the singular anonymous inner class doesn't equal the view you assigned handler to then it seems there is some critical detail that you are not sharing, either about your layout, your activity view construction, custom views, or some re-assignemnt of btnNext. It is unlikely anyone will be able to help unless you provide more information.

Under normal conditions all the approaches that have been listed will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping the IDs, and just compare the actually view object. so something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.equals(btnNext)) {
                ...
    }
}
```